# Need help creating a somewhat odd Excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to create a formula that takes C2-B2 and uses the result to determine which cells to add together. So if the result is 2 it takes AA2 and AB2, adds them together, and displays the result. In other words, it counts cells stemming from a point and adds them, with the amount counted determined by the result of two other cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesnt sound recursive the way you describe it.

Put this formula somewhere on the sheet and see if this is what you want:

`=SUM($AA$2:INDEX($AA$2:$XFD$2, 1, SUM($B$2:$C$2)))`

Comment: Tbh it's less complicated honestly because the addition parts used to be "run this formula using x where x goes up by one every time and the amount of runs is detained by c2-b2."

Comment: is the answer helping at all? I'm not sure where we are after your last comment. Is the b2-c2 range changing after the function is called?

Comment: It's working, sorry, I had to modify it just a little because the last bit is adding them instead of subtracting them (it's C2 minus B2) but now I've run into an issue where it's getting a circular reference from doing C2-B2 which, as postulated, does actually equal 2. I could see if it's equalling 0, but... And increasing C2 so the result is 5 instead makes it work.

Comment: @MarcoMarc I am slightly concerned if it's adding it correctly though, if I change the $AA$2 to anything else, particularly on the ones where *2-*2 is 0, it seems to just count the entire row instead...

Comment: Woo, found a solution using an If Else formula to tell it that if the result isn't greater than 0 to just return as 0.

Comment: Glad you got it working. Sorry i missed that the c2 was subtracting b2